# Dúvidas com propriedades de navegação e FK com Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Por que neste código foi identificado como chave estrangeira a propriedade IdGrupo e não a propriedade de navegação e qual seria a forma correta da aplicação da chave estrangeira?

```
public class Grupo
{
    public Grupo()
    {
        Produtoes = new List<Produto>();
    }

    public int GrupoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtoes { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int IdGrupo { get; set; }
    public decimal? Custo { get; set; }
    public decimal? Venda { get; set; }
    public decimal? Saldo { get; set; }
    public decimal? Promocao { get; set; }
    public virtual Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
}

public partial class DBContexto : DbContext
{
    static DBContexto()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DBContexto>(null);
    }

    public DBContexto()
        : base("DBContexto")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Grupo> Grupoes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Produto> Produtoes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Você chegou a gerar uma *Migration* deste código pra verificar se `IdGrupo` foi mesmo mapeada como chave estrangeira?

Comment: Cigano, ainda não usei o Migration neste código, só rodei o código para gerar as entidades no banco de dados, porém, constatei que os nomes tanto da propriedade de navegação quanto da FK não batem. Minha dúvida surgiu a partir daí, se tenho uma propriedade de navegação, por que esse código pegou IdGrupo como FK?

Comment: Se pegou, pra mim é algo novo. Possivelmente as convenções de nomes permitem que você use `IdGrupo` e `GrupoId`.

Comment: Em relação a gerar como chave estrangeira sim, o IdGrupo foi gerado como uma FK, mas qual foi o sentido então da propriedade de navegação Grupo?

Comment: Há vários. Por exemplo, se você quer escrever numa *View* o nome do Grupo tendo o Produto, pode fazer `produto.Grupo.Nome`. Se quer atribuir um novo Grupo ao Produto, pode fazer `produto.Grupo = db.Grupos.Single(/* Uma condição qualquer */)`. A enorme vantagem da propriedade de navegação é que o Entity Framework cuida dela por você.

Comment: Então o EF identifica automaticamente como uma FK as propriedades que possuem no nome ID, mesmo que eu não informe o Data Annotation [ForeignKey] e independente de eu criar ou não uma FK, só pelo fato de ter uma propriedade de navegação, o EF irá gerar uma FK pra mim?

Comment: Exatamente. Ele precisa relacionar as duas entidades de alguma forma, então verifica várias coisas, desde as propriedades de navegação até a *Fluent API*.

Comment: Obrigada Cigano!